# How do I "require" into current scope?

Tags: ruby, scope, require

I'm not 100% sure how Ruby variable scope works, and I'm having trouble using the `require "path.rb"` statement. Here's a code snippet that is causing the problem:

File a.rb:

```
a = {
        :hey => "ho"
    }

require "path/to/b.rb" # => true
```

File b.rb:

```
b = "harhar"
a[:test] = b
```

The scope of `a.rb` is inside a module::class, not the main global scope, and when I try and access the `a` variable within `b.rb` I get an error saying the `a` variable isn't in the current scope.

I read somewhere about included files being in their own scope so as not to clash, if so, what is the convention for getting around this?

Answer (score 2):

Top-level local variables are local to the file. Instead of using locals, you should use instance variables, module variables, methods, constants or globals — those are all visible from everywhere in your program. (Which one you want to use depends on the specific case at hand. Each way of storing data will make more sense in some cases than others.)

Comment: Does that also work if I want to use methods, e.g.: i'm in the context of a class A::B::C and I include "x.rb", and in "C" i have a method called "hello", how can I call "hello" from x.rb?

Comment: @tarnfeld: I'd put the method in a module. If you want it to be globally available as well, you can then include it in the global scope.